# Automatic object cache proxy with PHP

Tags: oop, caching, design-patterns, proxy

Here is a question on the Caching Proxy design pattern.

Is it possible to create with PHP a dynamic Proxy Caching implementation for automatically adding cache behaviour to any object?

Here is an example

```php
class User
{
    public function load($login)
    {
        // Load user from db 
    }

    public function getBillingRecords()
    {
        // a very heavy request
    }

    public function computeStatistics()
    {
        // a very heavy computing
    }
}

class Report
{
    protected $_user = null;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->_user = $user;
    }

    public function generate()
    {
        $billing = $this->_user->getBillingRecords();
        $stats = $this->_user->computeStatistics();

        /* 
            ...
            Some rendering, and additionnal processing code
            ...
        */
    }
}
```

you will notice that report will use some heavy loaded methods from User.

Now I want to add a cache system. 
Instead of designing a classic caching system, I just wonder if it is possible to implement a caching system in a proxy design pattern with this kind of usage:

```php
<?php
$cache = new Cache(new Memcache(...));

// This line will create an object User (or from a child class of User ex: UserProxy)
// each call to a method specified in 3rd argument will use the configured cache system in 2
$user = ProxyCache::create("User", $cache, array('getBillingRecords', 'computeStatistics'));
$user->load('johndoe');

// user is an instance of User (or a child class) so the contract is respected
$report = new report($user)
$report->generate(); // long execution time
$report->generate(); // quick execution time (using cache)
$report->generate(); // quick execution time (using cache)
```

each call to a proxyfied method will run something like:

```php
<?php
$key = $this->_getCacheKey();
if ($this->_cache->exists($key) == false)
{
    $records = $this->_originalObject->getBillingRecords();
    $this->_cache->save($key, $records);
}

return $this->_cache->get($key);
```

Do you think it is something we could do with PHP? do you know if it is a standard pattern? How would you implement it?

It would require to

- implement dynamically a new child class of the original object
- replace the specified original methods with the cached one
- instanciate a new kind of this object

I think PHPUnit does something like this with the Mock system...

Comment: PHPUNIT uses some templates and an eval to do it... so it is clearly not suitable for prdo


https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/master/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L300

Comment: I'am late here, but as I was looking for the same question, a detailed post with possible solutions are here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485854/best-way-to-implement-a-decorator-pattern-for-method-result-caching-in-php

Answer (score 0):

You can use the decorator pattern with delegation and create a cache decorator that accepts any object then delegates all calls after it runs it through the cache.

Does that make sense?