# Type safe generic decorator in PHP

Tags: php, reflection, types, decorator

I'd like to create a generic logging [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) that is type safe.

I have a number of [repositories](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) (interfaces), and need a decorator for each that catches the exceptions they might throw, passes those to an instance of [LoggerInterface](https://github.com/php-fig/log) and then rethrows them. It's possible to create a dedicated decorator and test for each, though this is quite cumbersome (especially doing the test nicely), and something I rather avoid.

Using `__call` to create a more generic decorator is the first approach that comes to mind. This however results in an object instance that does not implement the repository interface it decorates. That is a no go in my project. Is there some way to tell PHP that it does implement this interface, such as by use of some magic [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php)?

I've read "[how to implement a decorator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948443/how-to-implement-a-decorator-in-php)" and "[Best way to implement a decorator pattern for method result caching in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485854/best-way-to-implement-a-decorator-pattern-for-method-result-caching-in-php)" here on stackoverflow, both which outline the dedicated and the generic approach, though neither offer an indication of doing the generic approach in a type safe manner. Some time has passed since those questions where posted, so perhaps things have changed. I'm using PHP 7 and can use PHP 7.1 if needed.

[PHPUnit_MockObject](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects) allows constructing an object implementing an interface, via the same code that gets invoked by the familiar `getMock` method in PHPUnit. That can be the basis of a generic decorator. However that would require using a mocking library in production code. Furthermore, this library [internally uses eval](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit-mock-objects/blob/5d8c2a839d2c77757b7499eb135f34f9f5f07e6f/src/Framework/MockObject/Generator.php#L333-L342) to gets its job done. This disqualifies it for my project.

Comment: god, I thought I'll never see something about type-safeness in PHP here

Comment: Why not just create a custom exception handler that does the logging for you? If you only want to catch exceptions from your repositories, just  be sure to throw a special RepositoryException (more specific exceptions can extend it if needed). A decorator seems like an overly complex solution to a simple problem.

Comment: Interesting, I had not though of that. If I'm not mistaken, that would require me to let the exceptions go unhandled and bubble up, rather than potentially catch them where the repository is used. If so, the exception handler approach is not viable.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to dynamically create the decorated classes at runtime. Unfortunately [PHP doesn't allow this out of the box](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1593497/130121). If the [runkit](http://php.net/runkit) extension is not an option, you could emulate what [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) does: Have a `DecoratorFactory` that does the following steps:

- use Reflection on the original class to get all the interfaces and their methods,
- generate a file with PHP code containing a decorated proxy class that implements all the interfaces
- include the generated proxy class
- instantiate the generated proxy class with the original class and return the proxy class.

See an example at http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.4/source-class-Doctrine.ORM.Tools.EntityGenerator.html

Comment: As far as I can tell, the latest release of Runkit does not support PHP 7. What Doctrine ORM does is similar to PHPUnit_MockObject. It creates the code in string form and then evaluates that. Are you aware of a library that provides only the required functionality?

Answer (score 0):

The only real way you're going to get what you're after is to declare a base Decorator class that fully implements the necessary interface and then extend based on that. Eg:

```
interface FooInterface {
    function doFoo();
    function doMoreFoo();
}

class Foo implements FooInterface {
    public function __construct() {}
    public function doFoo() {}
    public function moreFoo() {}
}

class FooDecoratorBase implements FooInterface {
    protected $foo;
    public function __construct(FooInterface $foo) { $this->foo = $foo; }
    public function doFoo() { $this->foo->doFoo(); }
    public function moreFoo() { $this->foo->moreFoo(); }
}

class ExtraFooDecorator extends FooDecoratorBase {
    public function extraFoo() {}
}
```

Though I can't cite the specifics myself, I've been told by other PHP devs whom I respect that using Reflections in production code is a bad idea as they were designed with testing/debugging in mind, not performance.

Comment: I need a decorator that is generic in that it does the same kind of task for different interfaces, not different tasks for the same interface. I concur that using reflection is generally bad in production code, and have not done so in years. There are always exceptions though. Still, a solution without reflection is certainly preferred.

Answer (score 0):

"Generic TypeParameters" are not available in PHP [(except Facebook's HHVM variation)](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/generics/introduction). So this is not possible. The [answer of @Sammitch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36992985/2441442) is the way to go, if you realy want to go this path.

However, you are trying to solve a different problem.

The decorator pattern acts as a wrapper. You use it, if you want to add additional functionality for an existing class, **without changing the class itself (or it's object state)**.

Please think about, how your Decorator would be:

```
function DoSomeOperation() {
    try {
        return $this->decoratedObject->DoSomeOperation(); //Object is injected in Decorators Constructor
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        Logger::Log($ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Why not simple do it without a Decorator in your Repository:

```
function DoSomeOperation() {
    try {
        //Do The Logic
    catch (\Exception $ex) {
        Logger::Log($ex);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But maybe a Decorator/Wrapper for the PDO Object is, what you are realy want to have? (ᵔᴥᵔ)

Comment: Logging in my repository implementations would pollute them with the logging concern (SRP violation). It also makes the repositories more difficult to construct, as I'd need to inject the logger. (Using static binding and global state such as in your example code is very problematic.)

Comment: It was an example. You are free to inject your Logger Interface via a IoC. The logging concern is a logger. You don't want a logger to understand how an exeption should be handled, if that is what you think. If you `DoSomeOperation` and can handle a occuring `Exception` you should do it. It is the same concern. The *decorator pattern* has nothing to do with SRP. @JeroenDeDauw

Comment: I am not suggesting to make the logging code aware of specific exceptions. Seems we disagree on if the logging concern violates SRP or not. Rather than discuss that, lets keep it at that I do not want to inject loggers into my repositories.

Comment: Give an example of the acutal problem you want to solve... If we would ignore the word `TypesSafe`, how would your `Decorator` be? I am 100 % sure, you have missunderstood something @JeroenDeDauw.