# Duplicating code while using Cache with Decorator pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, decorator, dry

I have a Provider class and decorating one, CacheProviderDecorator class.
The trouble is that I need to cache the result of method, which is called inside of other provider's method:

For example, in Provider class:

```
    public function getUser(int $id): array
{
    return json_decode($this->client->get('user/' . $id)->getBody()->getContents(), true);
}


    public function getUsers(array $usersIds): array
{
    $usersSurnames = new Collection();

    foreach ($usersIds as $userId) {
        $usersSurnames->push($this->getUser($userId)['surname']);
    }

    return $usersSurnames->toArray();
}
```

CacheProviderDecorator class:

```
    public function getUser(int $id): array
{
    $key = self::PROJECT_USER . '_' . $id;

    return $this->cache->remember($key, self::TTL, function () use ($id) {
        return $this->provider->getUser($id);
    });
}
```

And because of `getUser()` is only used inside of `getUsers()`, I have to duplicate `getUsers()` method from Provider, else the Provider's `getUsers()` will be always called, and Provider's `getUser()` then too (because of $this->).

There are a plenty of such repeats. Is there any good architectural solution instead?

Comment: also, I think there should be no methods which don't do any requests inside of Provider class (that part has been written by another man)
perhaps it'll be good to just move  the `getUsers()` method into some Service class?

Comment: Look at that link which talks about the same problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17485854/best-way-to-implement-a-decorator-pattern-for-method-result-caching-in-php